# Visual Studio 2019 Edit and Continue not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, edit-and-continue

I have a VS 2019 Community edition installed. And I just installed the latest (update) Version 16.10.4.

My project is a .NET Core 3.1 web application (Asp / MVC / C#).

For some time now (I think it's 3 or 4 Visual Studio updates ago (within general version 2019), but I'm not sure which one broke it) Edit and continue is not working. If I stop at a breakpoint while debugging and make even the slightest changes to the code I get an error:

`Edits were made to the code which cannot be applied while debugging.`
`Click Stop to stop debugging.`
`Click Edit to make changes to the code`

A simplified example: I have `var counter = 1;` and I change it to `var counter = 1 + 1;` while debugging and I get the the before-mentioned error.

I have checked/tried this - with no success:
[Github - Edit and continue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/debugger/how-to-enable-and-disable-edit-and-continue.md)

Also, the same problem here:
[MS Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/1691-and-1692-Edit-And-Continue-Brok/1374733)
and the solution should be update to Version 16.10.4, but that doesn't really solve the issue.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Based on my test, I find that I can use the Edit and Contine function normally.   How do you debugging the app? I used 'F11' to debug it. By the way, the latest vs community version is 16.11.0.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT apparently I missed the latest version yesterday. I installed 16.11.0 this morning and now the problem is gone. Thank you :)

Comment: I have made an answer and if you don't mind, you could accept it as an answer. It will also help others to solve the simliar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer for the comment, the solution is that we can update the vs2019 version to 16.11.0.